# Finr the first term and the difference of an arithmetic progression, given two relations between its terms

Tags: sequences-and-series, algebra-precalculus, arithmetic-progressions

> In an AP, the 15th term is double the 9th term. If also, the sum of the first 15 and the sum of the first 9 terms added together is 279, find the first term and the common difference.

Alright, so we have to make two equations and solve them simultaneously.

First equation is pretty easy:

$$a + 14d = 2(a+8d)  $$

How do we make the second equation? the formula for sum of an AP is:

$S_n = (\frac n2)[2a + (n-1)d]$ where a is the first term and d is the common difference

We can't use the value of 279 because  that's for the 15th *and* the 9th term.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The sum of the first $15$ terms is $\frac{15}2 (2a + 14d)$, and the sum of the first $9$ terms is $\frac{9}{2}(2 a + 8d)$.

Their sum together is $279$, so
$$\frac{15}2 (2a + 14d) + \frac{9}{2}(2 a + 8d) = 279$$

is your second equation.

Comment: @thezaynthe Do you understand 5xum's answer?

Comment: @BLAZE Im kinda sad now that I didnt think of this myself...

Answer (score -1):

Each new term equals the previous term plus the common difference. So for 9 terms we add the common difference 8 additional times for a total of sum of 1 to 8 with the common difference of 1, which is 36. Hence the second equation:
         **9a+36d=279 or a+4d=31**
solve with the first equation of
         **2(a+8d)=a+14d or a=-2d**
The solution is:
  **a=-31**
  **d=15.5**

Comment: This answer is poorly formatted and confusingly written. Not to mention, incorrect. The second equation is different (see my answer).  You forgot the sum of the first $15$ elements.